# can we store shared preference on SD CARD

Tags: android

My android application is getting large and we want to store it in SD CARD. can i store shared preference in SD CARD along with my application

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify where shared preferences are stored. Since shared preferences are simply stored in an XML file, you are welcome to read and write XML data on external storage as you see fit.